# Should the following queries take 1 minute or more to complete?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

The following queries use 80% or more CPU and can take more than 1 minute to complete. 
My question: Is there anything wrong with my queries that would cause CPU usage like that? Can I decrease CPU usage and query time by optimizing the MySQL server conf?

Query 1 (loan_history contains 2.6 million records)

```
SELECT officer, SUM(balance) as balance
FROM loan_history
WHERE bank_id = '1'
AND date ='2013-07-04'  
AND officer IS NOT NULL
AND officer <> ''
GROUP BY officer
ORDER BY officer;
```

Query 2 (loan_history contains 2.6 million records)

```
SELECT SUM(weighted_interest_rate) as total
FROM (SELECT balance, tmp1.balance_sum,
    (balance / tmp1.balance_sum * interest_rate) as weighted_interest_rate
    FROM loan_history,
(SELECT SUM(balance) balance_sum FROM loan_history
WHERE date = '2013-07-04'
    AND bank_id = '1') as tmp1
WHERE date = '2013-07-04'
AND bank_id = '1') tmp2
```

Table information:

```
CREATE TABLE `loan_history` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`bank_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`loan_purpose_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`credit_grade` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`interest_rate` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
`officer` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`days_delinquent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41` (`bank_id`),
 KEY `IDX_9F5FE3F6F593857` (`loan_purpose_id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 KEY `credit_grade` (`credit_grade`),
 KEY `officer` (`officer`),
 KEY `start_date` (`start_date`),
 KEY `days_delinquent` (`days_delinquent`),
 KEY `interest_rate` (`interest_rate`),
 KEY `balance` (`balance`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_9F5FE3F11C8FB41` FOREIGN KEY (`bank_id`) REFERENCES `bank` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_9F5FE3F6F593857` FOREIGN KEY (`loan_purpose_id`) REFERENCES     `loan_purpose` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2630634 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Query 1 EXPLAIN:

```
| id | select_type | table        | type        | possible_keys                    | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                                                   |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | loan_history | index_merge | IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41,date,officer | date,IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41 | 3,5     | NULL | 4829 | Using intersect(date,IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

Query 2 EXPLAIN:

```
| id | select_type | table        | type        | possible_keys            | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra 

|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>   | ALL         | NULL                     | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL | 8236 |

|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>   | system      | NULL                     | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL |    1 |                             

|  2 | DERIVED     | loan_history | index_merge | IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41,date | date,IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41 | 3,5     | NULL | 4829 | Using intersect(date,IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41); Using where; Using index |

|  3 | DERIVED     | loan_history | index_merge | IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41,date | date,IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41 | 3,5     | NULL | 4829 | Using intersect(date,IDX_9F5FE3F11C8FB41); Using where; Using index |
```

My.cnf file:

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
interactive_timeout=300
key_buffer_size=256M
key_cache_block_size=4096
max_heap_table_size=128M
max_join_size=1000000000
max_allowed_packet=32M
open_files_limit=4096
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_limit=10240M
query_cache_type=1
table_cache=256
thread_cache_size=100
tmp_table_size=128M
wait_timeout=7800
max_user_connections=50
join_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M

innodb_open_files=300
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3000M
```

Comment: Do an EXPLAIN on your query

Comment: You're probably over-indexing here, but that's not necessarily the problem. The number of rows involved in the results can be important. What do you get if you query `SELECT count(*) FROM loan_history WHERE bank_id = '1' AND date ='2013-07-04' AND officer IS NOT NULL AND officer <> ''`?

Comment: Could you post a explain off your querys?

Comment: EXPLAIN has been added to query 1 and 2

Comment: You'll definitely need to post an `EXPLAIN` for Query 1 then. MySQL should be getting those 5,135 rows *very* quickly, and once it does the group/sort should also be fast.

Comment: EXPLAIN for query 1 and 2 have been added to above question.

Comment: What are the numbers of records you get out both querys could you also give this information? and the rows on a innodb are an estimate with the explain statement

Comment: Query 1 returns 52 records.  Query 2 returns 1 record(the total)

Comment: I suspect MySQL is having trouble selecting an appropriate index.  Try adding a composite index on (bank_id,date,officer) see if that helps.

Comment: Could you run querys to calculate your index Selectivity and post these results ?  SELECT  count(distinct your_indexed column) / count(*)   and this for all your indexes should take a while on innodb  because it will require a full table scan... if the value is close to 0 your index is useless if the value is close to 1 its a good index.   Your PRIMARY KEY index should have 1 if you test it whats why Composite Indexes are mentioned they have better selectivity.

Comment: I will do that right now @RaymondN. I will post results shortly, thx!

Comment: Besides the PRIMARY KEY all the other indexes are 0 - .08

Comment: **SOLVED** It turns out the VPS host was having major issues with their server. This was found after 2 hours on the phone with support. :\
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `sum()` and `GROUP BY` from the first query could be taking some time but I don't think there is much you can do there.

In the second query your `FROM (SELECT....` is probably hitting the system pretty hard, I would recommend turning

`(SELECT balance, tmp1.balance_sum,
    (balance / tmp1.balance_sum * interest_rate) as weighted_interest_rate
    FROM loan_history,
(SELECT SUM(balance) balance_sum FROM loan_history
WHERE date = '2013-07-04'
    AND bank_id = '1') as tmp1
WHERE date = '2013-07-04'
AND bank_id = '1')`

into a view or figuring out how to do it with JOINs

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us how much does exactly each one take. More than 1 minute each isn't that much indicative.

Any how, From [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html)

> When tuning a MySQL server, the two most important variables to configure are key_buffer_size and table_cache. You should first feel confident that you have these set appropriately before trying to change any other variables.

Also, take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size).

As for optimization, first try a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).